# Argument type 'Future<bool?> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm storing a `bool` value in shared preferences and getting the `bool` data using the `future<bool>` method in the `main.dart` file.

I need to use a future builder to handle this function, and that's where I encounter the error:

```
Argument type 'Future<bool?> Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<bool>'
```

Here is my code:

```dart
Authenticate extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold
      body: FutureBuilder<bool> (
        future: getBoolValuesSF,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool?> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == false) {
            return SignInPage();
          } else {
            return _handleAuth();
          }
        },
      ), // FutureBuilder
    ); // Scaffold
  }

  Widget _handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return (!snapshot.hasData) ? SignInPage() : FirstNavigation();
      },
    ); // StreamBuilder
  }

  Future<bool?> getBoolValues SF() async {
    SharedPreferences loginCheck = await SharedPreferences.getInstance(); 
    return loginCheck.getBool("state");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [avoid uploading code as picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the function.

```
future: getBoolValuesSF()
```

You probably also need to change the return type of this function, as you won't be able to assign `Future<bool?>` to `Future<bool>`. In other words, make sure you function always returns a bool (and never `null`) and change the return type accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me. I also changed the  body: FutureBuilder<bool> to  body: FutureBuilder<bool?>